# Importing libraries/JARs in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I understand that this is a relatively common question, but I've followed the answers to so many of these at this point and none of them work.

I'm using Eclipse (on Mac now although I had the issue on Windows) and I want to learn the LWJGL which is a library for Java. I downloaded all the jars, and copied them into a lib folder:
[image: Screenshot-2021-10-17-at-17-15-57.png]

then, as an example I added 3 of them to the project's build path, so that they appear in the referenced libraries section

[image: Screenshot-2021-10-17-at-17-17-24.png]

Now, although I can literally see that `org.lwjgl` for example is in my referenced libraries, I am always unable to use it in my code...

[image: Screenshot-2021-10-17-at-17-18-48.png]
[image: Screenshot-2021-10-17-at-17-19-21.png]

does anyone know why this keeps happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a *modularized* Java application, that is, one that uses the Java 9+ module system with its **module path** and not the pre-Java-Module-System **classpath**.

So you are going to have to declare a dependency in your project's `module-info.java` as well, making it look something like:

```java
module whatever.your.app.module.is {
  requires org.lwjgl;
  requires org.lwjgl.natives;
  requires org.lwjgl.glfw;
  requires org.lwjgl.glfw.natives;
  requires org.lwjgl.opengl;
  requires org.lwjgl.opengl.natives;
}
```

The important parts are the `requires` declarations in your `module-info.java` file, which you have to add.

Merely adding the LWJGL jar files to Eclipse's *module path* (as opposed to its *classpath*) will not make the classes available to your modularized Java application.

An alternative to a modularized Java application is one that *does not* use the Java Module System. In this case, you can simply delete your `module-info.java` file and add LWJGL's jar files (*including* the ones with "natives" in their names) to Eclipse's build path classpath (as opposed to the "modulepath").

Comment: this is perfect, thank you so much! Although after this I found out GLFW is apparently not supported on Apple M1.. yikes

Comment: this makes a lot of sense. However when I do this, I then get a new error:
[LWJGL] Platform/architecture mismatch detected for module: org.lwjgl
 JVM platform:
  macOS x86_64 16.0.2
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM v16.0.2+7-67 by Oracle Corporation
 Platform available on classpath:
  macos/arm64

Comment: well that's the confusing part, because I do..
[see this image of the 'about my mac'](https://postimg.cc/PCYZbmVy)
and when I use the x64 natives I get 'cocoa failed to find service port for display'. Or sometimes the window appears as expected but the cocoa error still shows in the console